# can we determine home directory of the currently logged in Windows user using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

can we determine  home directory of the currently logged in Windows user using Javascript?

For example, C:\Users\LENOVO.

Comment: if you are asking about doing this from web browser the answer is absolutely not

Comment: Please provide more context.

Comment: If it was possible, it would be a huge security flaw. Any website you visit could browse your personal files.

Comment: If you aren't asking about doing this from a web browser, then you need to be more specific. The answers using Node.JS and WSH (for example) will probably be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done within a web browser for obvious security reasons.

Browsers will even return a fake path when querying for the value of a file `input` element.

```
<input type="file" id="file">

$("#file").val(); // Returns something like C:/fakepath/image.jpg
```